# Building mongoose queries programmatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to do a kind of a complex mongoose query. I have searched around and found solutions asking for single variables(with if) and building the query object, but I wanted to know if there is a simpler way because I would be building a query with about 40 non required parameters, for example right now in my `req.body` I have:

```
{ searchParams:
   { publicationType: 'Venta',
     subtype: [ 'Duplex', 'Cabaña' ],
     address:
      {
        streetNumber: '1312',
        streetName: 'José María Bosch',
        city: 'Villa Bosch',
        state: 'Buenos Aires',
        country: 'Argentina' } 
    }
}
```

All the names are the same in the database, what I have to do I search if `publicationType` matches, if the address matches and finally for sub type if any of those array items matches since subtype is a string. Is there any way to do it without an if for each field?

Right now I did this simple query to try out

```
router.post('/search', (req, res, next) => {
    model.Dwelling.find(req.body.searchParams).lean().exec().then(
        dwellings => res.send({dwellings})
    ).catch(next);
});
```

It works on `publicationType` and `subtype` buy not on `address`.

this is an object in my data base:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5af06167ea174f00142bab91"
    },
    "publicationType": "Alquiler",
    "address": {
        "latitude": -34.59250669999999,
        "altitude": -58.571258599999965,
        "streetNumber": "1312",
        "streetName": "José María Bosch",
        "city": "Villa Bosch",
        "state": "Buenos Aires",
        "country": "Argentina"
    },
    "type": "Residencial",
    "subtype": "Casa",
    "currency": "",
    "price": 50000,
    "occupationStatus": "Disponible",
    "spaces": {
        "rooms": 3,
        "floors": 0,
        "bedrooms": 0,
        "closets": 0,
        "bathRoom": 0,
        "toilette": 0,
        "living": false,
        "livingDining": false,
        "diningRoom": false,
        "kitchen": false,
        "kitchenDining": false,
        "terrace": false,
        "balcony": false,
        "backYard": false,
        "swimmingPool": false,
        "barbecue": false,
        "garage": "No",
        "laundryRoom": "No"
    },
    "features": {
        "status": "Desconocido",
        "orientation": "Desconocida",
        "luminosity": "Desconocida",
        "heating": [
            {
                "value": "No posee",
                "label": "No posee"
            }
        ],
        "refurbished": false,
        "repair": "No"
    },
    "services": {
        "gas": true,
        "water": true,
        "sewer": true,
        "phone": true,
        "pavement": true,
        "electricity": true,
        "cableTv": true
    },
    "legal": {
        "bank": false,
        "prof": false
    },
    "generalDescription": "Desc 1",
    "privateDescription": "Desc 2",
    "siocId": 713675,
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2018-05-07T14:23:35.230Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2018-05-07T14:23:35.230Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Your desired functionality of "what i have to do i search if publicationType matches, if the address matches and finally for sub type if any of those array items matches since subtype is a string" is hard to understand. Can you update your question with specific query examples?

Comment: i added the query im using